Smoking on a hotel room's balcony in Greece
I am investigating Greece as a possible tourist destination and spoke to a friend who has recently (Summer 2024) been there. She said that, in the next room to hers, people smoked on their balcony. Is this legally allowed in Greece? Can I demand forbidding smoking on a balcony if I am in a hotel in Greece, and will I have a high chance of success if I do?
More broadly, is there a Mediterranean country with a good access to the seaside where smoking is definitely forbidden and where I don't need to bother with reporting it at all?
Edited: I re-read the last question and it is a bit broad. What I meant to find was a Mediterranean country where smoking is forbidden inside hotels in general, excluding special places that are easy to avoid. Obviously, it cannot be forbidden countrywide.

The answer would have more to do with the owner or hotel operator's approach to the business: are they more interested in obeying the law, or in allowing their customers to act as they wish? The answer would also be affected by the balcony and room layout...who can smell the smoke, and how much? I doubt that this is answerable in an applies-to-all-cases manner.

I referred to Overview of smoke-free legislation and its implementation in the EU which for Greece says "Hotels and Accommodation – total ban".

Perhaps the balcony smokers are tourists from a less restrictive country and don't understand the law. But, once you start raising complaints, there is often only one way the experience as a whole can go: downhill.

@WeatherVane I am pretty sure that the 'total ban' for smoking in Greek hotels only apply to indoor areas. Even the document you are linking to specify just a few lines further down, that there are no bans for outdoor areas.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I don't think your approach is necessarily the most constructive or would be considered reasonable in any European country but the document found by WeatherVane contains some data on self-reported smoking exposure that could be interesting for your purpose.
Among Mediterranean countries, Italy has the lowest exposures in bars (11%) and restaurants (7%), followed by Spain, Malta and then Cyprus. Greece is much much worse with over 70% exposure in both bars and restaurants during the last 6 months, which is consistent with your anecdote. Assuming this is broadly correlated with smoking prevalence and attitudes towards smoking and with the caveat that the data is over 10 years old, Italy would therefore seem like a good choice (and indeed I don't recall much smoking there but I am not overly sensitive to it).

Yes, it makes sense, thank you. Interestingly enough, Cyprus is high in the list, and Greece is low, and I considered them to be very close culturally.

Bear in mind that people will smoke on balconies in Italy too, and this is often explicitly facilitated with ashtrays on the balconies (I've seen this as recent as 2023). If this is a concern, book rooms in larger hotels with windows in a façade without balconies, rent an apartment, or book a room in a small boutique hotel without balconies. If you really want to avoid smoking near your room, consider wellness hotels where asking about this may be more common.

@Mykola Italian. My 2¢:  amongst my personal friends (aged professionals in northern Italy) smoking on a balcony is seen as perfectly OK. Further, I don't smoke at all but I see smoking on balconies as perfectly OK. I can definitely say that there is NO SOCIAL STIGMA re smoking on balconies. On the other hand, people is very strict/respectful re smoking in closed areas.

Smoking on a private balcony might be different legally than smoking on a hotel balcony,

@Mykola keep in mind that not every situation where a neighboring balcony has people smoking on it will be problematic. It will depend on wind direction, whether there is a wall that reduces air circulation, whether the windows are large or small (if open) or well sealed (if closed), whether the smoking is frequent or occasional, etc. In a big hotel you might be able to get a different room. And keep in mind that the law is only part of the story: on several occasions in the last few years, I've been in rooms that had obviously been smoked in by previous occupants, despite the ban.

If people are smoking on their own balcony, and it's outside, and it's not illegal, most Europeans would be of the opinion that it's their own business.

It's a few years since I was last in Greece, but my experience is that they treat smoking bans in rather the same way that they treat speed limits.

@AlanB This is why I am asking - obviously, when it is legal, I have neither leverage nor desire to complain.

Ask your hotel before booking, they may have a wing of the hotel which is non-smoking

As per the document referenced by WeatherVane, smoking is prohibited everywhere in hotels in the EU - with exceptions to smoking rooms that must not let smoke out to any other place in the hotel. I do not want to write to every hotel that I find potentially suitable during my research, it is too time consuming

From my experience (as a European) "IN hotels" usually means indoors, if not otherwise stated. At least in practice I almost never see problems with people smoking outside, even on train stations where it is explicitly forbidden also outdoors (eg. in Austria), nobody cares and nobody gets reprimanded or fined.

@Mykola in Greece, assume that smoking is allowed on the balconies. Maybe there are some specialist hotels that have special rules, but on average, assume that smoking will at the very least be tolerated.

@Mykola Smoking on balconies, at least in Italy, is normal. Irrespectful of what you want to do, you will need to consume your time to find an accomodation fulfilling your requirements.
